# For the following code, how to solve the problem of motor speed setting failure?

Tags: python-3.x, motordriver

When running in the program, no matter how I set the speed, the motor can rotate normally, but the obtained speed is always 100. I set the speed to 500 and the result is still 100 after running. I don't know whether it is the program operation problem or the setting. The reason for this is very strange to me, and I hope the technical gods can help solve it. Thank you very much.
'

```
import serial
import time
import struct
from binascii import unhexlify
from crcmod import mkCrcFun
import binascii
import crcmod


motor_speed_mode = b'\x01\x2F\x60\x60\x00\x03\x00\x00\x00\x0D'
motor_status = b'\x01\x43\x50\x00\x51\x00\x68\x95'
motor_start = b'\x01\x44\x21\x00\x31\x00\x00\x01\x00\x01\x75\x34'
motor_stop = b'\x01\x44\x21\x00\x31\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\xE5\x34'   # AB轴失能
    
class SpeedMotor:
    def __init__(self, device,speed_v,speed_a):
        # 真实速度
        self.rel_speed = 0
        # 设置的速度
        self.set_speed1 = speed_v
        # 设置角速度
        self.set_speed2 = speed_a
        # 运行状态
        self.run = False
        # 故障状态
        self.fault = None
        # 电机电压
        self.voltage = 0
        # 电机电流
        self.current = 0
        # 设置串口通讯
        self.serial = serial.Serial(device, 115200)
        self.serial.timeout = 0
        # 设置为速度模式
        self.serial.write(motor_speed_mode)
        time.sleep(0.1)
        # 设置加减速度
 #       self.serial.write(b'\x0A\x14\x14\x32')
 #       time.sleep(0.1)

    def check_code(self,byte0, byte1, speed_vel, speed_ang):
        '计算校验码时需要输入的字节'
        read = byte0+byte1+speed_vel+speed_ang  #解析校验码要输入的前几位
        read=(str(binascii.b2a_hex(read))[2:-1])
        #print (read)
        return(read)

    def crc16_modbus(self,read):
        '输出的控制电机指令字节码'
        crc16 =crcmod.mkCrcFun(0x18005,rev=True,initCrc=0xFFFF,xorOut=0x0000)
        data = read.replace(" ","")
        #print (data)
        readcrcout=hex(crc16(unhexlify(data))).upper()
        str_list = list(readcrcout)
        if len(str_list) < 6:
            str_list.insert(2, '0'*(6-len(str_list)))  # 位数不足补0
        crc_data = "".join(str_list)
        #print(crc_data)
        read = read.strip()+crc_data[4:]+crc_data[2:4]
        read = bytes.fromhex(read)
        #print(read)
        return (read)
        
    def motor_speed_vel(self,speed_v,speed_a):
        '计算小车线速度speed_v'
        DEC1 = speed_v
        DEC2 = speed_a
        byte2 =(struct.pack("i",DEC1)[-4:-3])#线速度
        byte3 =(struct.pack("i",DEC1)[-3:-2])#线速度
        speed_vel = byte2 + byte3
        byte4 = (struct.pack("i",DEC2)[-4:-3])    #角速度两个字节
        byte5 = (struct.pack("i",DEC2)[-3:-2])
        speed_ang = byte4+byte5
        print (speed_vel,speed_ang)
        return (speed_vel,speed_ang)
    #motor_speed_vel(200,20)

    def motor_speed_set(self):
        '速度设置'
        byte0 = b'\x01'
        byte1 = b'\xEA'
        speed_vel = motor_speed_vel(self.set_speed1)
        speed_ang = motor_speed_vel(self.set_speed2)  #motor_speed_ang(self.set_speed2) 
        read = self.check_code(byte0, byte1, speed_vel, speed_ang)
        speed_code = read
        self.serial.write(speed_code)

    def motor_start(self):
        '启动'
        self.serial.write(motor_start)
        self.run = True
    def motor_stop(self):
        '停止'
        self.run = False
        self.serial.write(motor_stop)
 
m = SpeedMotor('COM5',500,20)    #这里要改成nano对应的USB2口，如果插电脑测试就是COM3
m.motor_start()
for i in range(300):
   m.set_speed =i
time.sleep(15)
m.motor_stop()
```

''''